# SQL joint tables Сортировка

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Union or full joint movies and users]

Determine which lead studio's movies are favorited by users the most.
Подскажите как выбрать ведущую кино-компанию (lead_studio) по пользователям?

```sql
SELECT * FROM movies LEFT JOIN users on movie_id = favorite_movie_id
UNION
SELECT * FROM movies RIGHT JOIN users on movie_id = favorite_movie_id;
```

Моя логика:

```sql
select * from movies join users on movie_id = favorite_movie_id;
```

нужно сгруппировать lead_studio чтобы не было повторений
и затем нужно отталкиваться  от `favorite_movie_id`. То есть чье кино выбрал пользователь идет в копилку компании
Но как это написать вообще не представляю

Answer (score 1):

```
Select m.lead_studio
from movies m
left join users u on m.movie_id = u.favorite_movie_id
group by m.lead_studio
order by count(u.favorite_movie_id) desc
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: INNER JOIN будет достаточно, незачем всё тащить из таблицы movies, если интересует инфа в разрезе пользователей

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите пример

```
-- test data
create table movies (movie_id int,lead_studio varchar(20));
insert into movies values
 (1,'Fox')
,(2,'Disney')
,(3,'Paramount')
,(4,'Paramount')
,(5,'Warner bros.')
;
create table users (user_id int,favorite_movie_id int);
insert into users values
 (1001,2)
,(1002,3)
,(1003,4)
,(1005,2)
,(1006,5)
;
-- query
with favorites as( -- выбираем фильмы-фавориты и количество пользователей, их выбравших
select favorite_movie_id ,count(user_id) cnt
from users
group by favorite_movie_id
)
,favorite_counts as ( -- считаем сумму выбранного по каждой студии
select  lead_studio,coalesce(sum(cnt),0) cnt
  ,rank()over(order by sum(cnt) desc) rnk -- упорядочиваем по популярности
from movies m
left join favorites f on f.favorite_movie_id=m.movie_id
group by lead_studio
)
select lead_studio
from favorite_counts
where rnk=1  -- выбираем самые популярные студии
```

Можно применить INNER JOIN, если действительно нужны только самые популярные строки.

Промежуточный результат

| lead_studio | cnt | rnk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Disney | 2 | 1 |
| Paramount | 2 | 1 |
| Warner bros. | 1 | 3 |
| Fox | 0 | 4 |

Результат

| lead_studio |
| --- |
| Disney |
| Paramount |

[Fiddle пример](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rmt_TMgq)